# Dynamically create HTML forms not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create several forms for the options page of a Chrome extension, but when I click 'add', the forms do not appear.

`options.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Test Extension Options</title></head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My Tabs</h1>
  </header>
  <form id='fields'>
    <button id="createNew">Add...</button>
  </form>

  <div id="status"></div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>

</body>
  <script src="./js/options.js"></script>
</html>
```

`options.js`

```
function render_form() {
  let counter = 0;
  let newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
  document.getElementById('fields').appendChild(newdiv);
  counter++;
}

document.getElementById('createNew').addEventListener('click', render_form());
```

When I take out the invocation from the very last line (ie saying `render_form` instead of `render_form()`), the input field will not be there at all, but when I do invoke, the initial field will be there, but nothing will happen upon clicking the `Add...` button.

Comment: `addEventListener('click', render_form())` needs to be `addEventListener('click', render_form)`

Comment: also add `type='button'` to your Add `<button>` as default is submit and will cause form to submit...or prevent default with javascript in your listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is using only non-Chrome API basic HTML + JavaScript (which yours is) and it does not work in a regular browser page environment, then it is not going to work in a Chrome extension options page or popup.

Your code, as it is, does not function because you are trying to assign the return value from `render_form()` as your event listener with:

```
addEventListener('click', render_form());
```

If you change that to actually assign the `render_form` function as the event listener:

```
addEventListener('click', render_form);
```

it will actually add the `<input>` elements.  It probably isn't exactly what you are wanting (i.e. `counter` is always `0`).

Your question implies that you want one entry field to be there by default. Thus, I have added an invocation of the `render_form()` function after adding it as a listener.  I have also moved `counter` to be global so that your counting works as I believe you desire.

```js
var counter = 0;
function render_form() {
  let newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML="Entry "+(counter + 1)+" <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/>";
  document.getElementById('fields').appendChild(newdiv);
  counter++;
}

document.getElementById('createNew').addEventListener('click', render_form);
render_form();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Test Extension Options</title></head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My Tabs</h1>
  </header>
  <form id='fields'>
    <button id="createNew" type='button'>Add...</button>
  </form>

  <div id="status"></div>
  <button id="save" type='button'>Save</button>

</body>
  <!-- Comment out the external script which is required in a Chrome popup,
       but which does not work in a Stack Overflow snippet.
  <script src="./js/options.js"></script>
  -->
</html>
```

In addition to this snippet, I have tested the above code in Google Chrome as the options page for an extension. It works fine in that context.

Here is the *manifest.json* file I used to test this as both a Google Chrome extension and as a Firefox WebExtension [Note: this *manifest.json* uses the same *options.html* as both an [options_ui](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) page and a [browser_action popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups)]:

```
{
    "description": "Demonstrate changing the HTML of options.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "change-option-form-demo",
    "version": "0.1",

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            //Firefox: must define id to use option_ui:
            "id": "change-option-form-demo@example.example",
            "strict_min_version": "48.0"
        }
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "myIcon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Show panel",
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_popup": "options.html"
    },

    "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html",
      "chrome_style": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Added you code, but when I click Add... You can see the new element appear for a split second, then disappear. If you click again, the same thing happens, but nothing is permanent.

Comment: @WillAshley, OK, then we are going to need a *complete* [mcve] (i.e. including *manifest.json*, etc.). I *have* tested exactly the above code and it works fine for me as both a Google Chrome Extension and a Firefox WebExtension. [Obviously you have to uncomment the `<script src="./js/options.js"></script>` line, but no changes are needed other than that.] I have updated the answer to include the *manifest.json* i used for testing in both Google Chrome and Firefox.